# What does "angry place" mean?

Tags: plot-explanation, oceans-8

In *Ocean's Eight (2018)*, two con artists Debbie Ocean and Lou are walking side by side:

> Debbie Ocean: So then I thought ten banks. Then I realized that would
> be maybe coming from an **angry place** so...
>
> Lou: Good you realized that.
>
> Debbie: Yes. Then I couldn't even hear myself think

What does "angry place" mean?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's an English Language comprehension question.

Comment: It really is a language comprehension question.  You might find [ELL StackExchange](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) to be another resource you might want to look into.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simply colloquial English for thoughts that you have when feeling angry or destructive.  An internal source for those thoughts if you prefer to think of it like that.

Saying "my/a happy place" is more common, meaning a place you go to in your head when you want to daydream about things that make you happy.  "an angry place" would be understood by the listener to be the opposite of that.